# iPad Scaling Issues in Website Build

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ipad

I tried searching for the better part of three days, but maybe I'm not asking my question right so I decided to try here.

I'm currently developing a website that I feel looks amazing, however on the iPad it's zoomed in with a ratio of 1 to 1 from the start. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this problem. On other websites that I built the iPad simply scales the view to fit into its viewing area. But sadly that is not the case for this.

[Here is the website currently](http://mud.cleartouchvisuals.com/)

I'm developing on Wordpress, using the Genesis Framework. Can someone please lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Viewport` meta tag to specify how you want your website to behave on different screens:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

It's the viewport meta tag that does this. Here's the one you are using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Comment: Yep. That part I did find out. Now do you know of anything I need to remove or add so I can get regular functionality back?